# How to deal with big arrays/lists

Tags: java, runtime-error, java-stream

recently I try to do codility tasks.
I often do a task with array as input, where you need to solve problem like: find smallest positive Integer which doesn't occur in array etc.
I can easily deal with small array, but when I sumbit code and get summary with tests including arrays having >1000 (or 10 000) elements I almost always have runtime error.

So can you tell me how to deal with big arrays?

Mostly I try to convert array to List like this:

```
List<Integer> arrayList = Arrays.stream(A)
                .boxed()
                .filter(c -> (c > -1001 && c < 1001)) // predicate
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Sometimes I use filter, like you see, sometimes I use distinct/sort if I need to.
But still I have a lot of runtime errors.

I'll be greatful for some tips how to deal with it.

@cricket_007

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.stream(A)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if ((integerList.size() == 2 && integerList.get(0) == integerList.get(1)) || A.length == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ((integerList.size() == 2 && integerList.get(0) != integerList.get(1))) {
            return Math.abs(integerList.get(0) - integerList.get(1));
        }

        int sublistSum1;
        int sublistSum2;

        List<Integer> scoreList = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer temp;
        for (int i = 1; i < integerList.size(); i++) {
            sublistSum1 = integerList.subList(0, i).stream().mapToInt(n -> n).sum();
            sublistSum2 = integerList.subList(i, integerList.size()).stream().mapToInt(n -> n).sum();
            temp = Math.abs(sublistSum1 - sublistSum2);
            scoreList.add(temp);
        }
        return scoreList.stream()
                .min(Integer::compareTo)
                .get();
    }
}
```

So this is my solution to this task: https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/tape_equilibrium/

I got 100% correctness, but 0% performance, because: "TIMEOUT ERROR Killed. Hard limit reached: 6.000 sec." All 6 performance test return this error.

What can I do in this case?

Next task, next problem with big array. https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/passing_cars/

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        if (Arrays.stream(A).distinct().count() == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        int score = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] == 0) {
                for (int j = 1; j < A.length; j++) {
                    if (A[j] == 1 && j > i) {
                        score++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (score < 1_000_001) {
            return score;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

So basically when I tried to solve this task with nested loop I got O(N^2) algorithm complexity. How to solve it?

Comment: What language is this? Java?

Comment: Yes, it's Java.

Comment: Next time tag the language you're asking about so people with experience in that language can find your question more easily and answer it.

Comment: What are those runtime errors you observed?

Comment: If you're getting timeout exceptions when submitting the task, that means you're missing the optimal solution, and you shouldn't be building that list anyway

Comment: If you only need to find a single integer, you do not need to allocate a collection.

Comment: I am sorry, I believe that this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Even if you narrowed it down to a simple example of a concrete task and a concrete program that solved it but took too long, it might still be too broad, but you may try that, then we’ll see.

Comment: @cricket_007 so how should I solve this task?
I tried to solve ~10 codility tasks, only once I got 100%. The biggest problem is related with this runtime error - big arrays (length >1000). How to find one element or what to do when you get big array in test?

Comment: I think you should link to a single problem that you're having issues with and your solution rather than ask a vague question about all the problems

Comment: I edited post, please read it and give me some hints how to solve my problems.

Comment: You should not turn your question into a growing set of tasks. Regarding “PassingCars”, remove this obsolete `Arrays.stream(A).distinct().count() == 1` pretest. Then, consider that the right hand sides do not change for the encountered left hand sides of the pairs; they are just counted multiple times. You can do that with a single loop by simply adding the count of lhs instead of incrementing by one: `public int solution(int[] A) { int score = 0, lhs = 0; for(int i = 0; i < A.length && score <= 1_000_000; i++) if(A[i] == 0) lhs++; else score += lhs; return score <= 1_000_000? score: -1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to ask yourself whether you really need a `List<Integer>` which requires boxing or if an `int[]` array would be sufficient for your task too.

So

```
int[] array = Arrays.stream(A)
    .filter(c -> (c > -1001 && c < 1001))
    .toArray();
```

will be far more efficient. But if you really need a `List<Integer>`, you still should do as much work as possible *before* boxing the values, i.e.

```
List<Integer> arrayList = Arrays.stream(A)
    .filter(c -> (c > -1001 && c < 1001))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way, only the matching `int` values are boxed rather than all of them. This is an optimization which the Stream implementation can’t perform itself, as when you use `.boxed().filter(c -> (c > -1001 && c < 1001))` you are invoking `filter` on a `Stream<Integer>`, passing a `Predicate<Integer>` rather than an `IntPredicate` and the implementation has no choice but to pass an `Integer` to that code.

Similar things apply to `sort`; it’s way more efficient when applied to primitive type data rather than `Integer` objects. There’s a similar potential for `distinct`, but afaik this does not materialize with the current implementation.

You have to implement better algorithms yourself then, which is what the challenge is all about.

One solution for finding the smallest positive integer not contained in an array would be

```
int first = Arrays.stream(A)
    .filter(i -> i >= 0)
    .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or)
    .nextClearBit(0);
```

If “positive” means “greater than zero”, you’d have to use `i > 0` and `nextClearBit(1)`. This solution would also support parallel processing.

Learning about existing algorithms and the data structures offered by the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html) is a necessity for such tasks. As well as knowing what truly doesn’t exist and needs to be implemented by yourself.

Comment: Well, your answer gave me few important informations.
Next question: now I'm trying to deal with task, where I need to find smalles difference between two arrays parts (something like sublists). How to solve it?
I tried to convert it to list, count sum of all sublists and finally use min() method (list.stream().min()), but still it takes too much time.